# How to filter an array when given the keyword and a list of fields to search?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code:

```
export function getByKeyword(list, keyword, searchFields) {
    const search = keyword.trim().toLowerCase()

    if (!search.length) {
        return list
    }

    return list.filter(item =>
        item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1 ||
        item.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1
    )
}
```

Currently I am using || and hardcoding the fields to search.

However I would like to make the function more reusable and pass in the searchFields which is an array of fields to search (e.g. [ 'name', 'email', 'group' ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
export function getByKeyword(list, keyword, searchFields) {
    const search = keyword.trim().toLowerCase()

    if (!searchFields.length) {
        return list
    }

    return list.filter(item =>{
        return searchFields.some(field=> item[field].toLowercase().includes(keyword));
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, nice and neat!

Comment: Having a problem when the field being searched is null. How would I ignore the null fields?

Comment: Got it done.
      return list.filter(item => {return filter_fields.some(field => (item[field] !== null) ? item[field].toLowerCase().includes(search) : '')
  })